# Adding CSS background image to Material UI theme

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, background-image, typeerror

In `material UI`, the theme can be adjusted and/or overridden using the `createMuiTheme` function. This is the full file in which I am doing so:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import purple from '@material-ui/core/colors/purple';
import green from '@material-ui/core/colors/green';

//import wood from './static/wood.png';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: purple[500],
    },
    secondary: {
      main: green[500],
    },
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      '@global': {
        body: {
          border: '2px solid blue',
          backgroundImage: 'url("/static/wood.png")',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

The global styling applied to the body is confirmed working- I can see the blue border. However, nothing I try will get the background image to work.

Normally, I would uncomment the import statement at the top: `import wood from './static/wood.png';` and then change the **CSS** line to:

```
backgroundImage: `url(${wood}),`
```

However, the import statement alone is causing a crash:

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function. It seems that there is something special about customizing a material ui theme that doesn't allow static assets to be imported in the same file.

When I instead attempt to use a url for the image (shown above), it is always a 404 error. My file structure places the image in `src > static > wood.png`, but I get:

> http://localhost:3000/static/wood.png 404 (not found).

I've tried dozens of possible `path` variations, but none have worked, and all my efforts to research the proper path just indicate that I'm already using the correct path.

Is it only possible to add a background image to the body using Material UI theme customization when the background image is hosted on a separate server?

The only working examples I've found do it that way (like this one: https://codesandbox.io/s/v30yq681ql), but it seems like there must be a way to use an image stored locally.

Or if the problem really is that my relative path is incorrect, what can I do to find out what the correct one would actually be?

If there is a better way to add a background image to a page with `Material UI` that would work too, though I haven't seen any other way to do it than a global override of the body tag.

Answer (score 6):

If you put your image within the `src` folder instead of `static`, e.g.

```
src/components/wood.png
```

Reinstate your import like:

```
import wood from './components/wood.png';
```

and then put the `backgroundImage` to:

```
backgroundImage: `url(${wood})`,
```

that should work. The same configuration (with different filename, but in the same location) works for me.